# What is "Dooley tracks"?

Tags: meaning

I've been watching *Breaking Bad* series and stumbled upon the **Dooley tracks** expression.

Here's some context:

> Got a couple of **Dooley tracks** headed away, towards the road.

What is **Dooley tracks** and who is **Dooley**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a fixed expression, but rather just the nickname of a type of vehicle used as a modifier before the noun *tracks*. These are tracks made by a "Dooley."

> "What is a **Dually Truck**?"
>
> If a truck is “dually,” it means it has dual rear wheels on either
> side.  [Badger](https://www.badgertruck.com/heavy-truck-information/what-is-a-dually-truck/)

> Officially, it was called the “1973 C-30 One-Ton **Dually**.” That's
> right. Most people refer to Chevy's pickups with the four wheels in
> the rear as a “**Dooley or “Doolie"—and it's commonly spelled that
> way.** Fact is, it's officially a “dually,” precisely because it has
> dual wheels on each rear side. [aldanamerican.com; "A New Generation of Chevy Trucks, and Their First “**Dooley**” ";](https://aldanamerican.com/blog/1973-a-new-generation-of-chevy-trucks-and-their-first-dooley/#:%7E:text=Officially%2C%20it%20was%20called%20the,wheels%20on%20each%20rear%20side.)

Here is the [**clip**](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/079b7a61-cfa5-4b90-b31c-6db2c8e36b10) from the *Breaking Bad episode.*

Comment: But it's **tracks**, not **trucks**.

Comment: I didn't know what a Dooley was and had to look it up, but I presumed it was a vehicle and not a species of antelope.

Comment: Crystal-clear! Thank you.

Comment: [Deleted comment] Yes, "Dooley tracks," tracks left by a Dooley truck.

Comment: Dooley noted! :)